# Subdomain redirection

Tags: subdomain, redirection

I have a subdomain like www.product.example.com for the domain www.example.com.
Can I redirect the subdomain to another website without showing the url of other website for users, when they click on the subdomain link?
Please help me in this

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's called cloaking. It basically works by creating a frame that occupies the entire browser window, then loads the target page in the frame.

e.g.

```
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0" frameborder="0">
<frame name="__main" src="http://www.example.com/" noresize frameborder="0">
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're responsible for both Web sites, you could put SQUID in front of them and handle it on the backend.  (See: transparent proxy)

Answer (score -1):

If you use zoneedit (www.zoneedit.com) for the DNS management of your domain www.example.com, you could achieve this easily at the DNS level. Thousands including myself use zoneedit for many years. It's free. Let's say you have a domain registered through godaddy. In your godaddy dns management:
1. Use Zone Edit's DNS server name instead of the DNS server of your hosting company. 
2. Then in Zoneedit add that domain and add the hosting provider's IP address A Record
3. Then click on web forward and add your subdomain. It should update this within a few minutes. Here is an example screen capture: http://www.diigo.com/item/image/1effz/mnhp

Hope this helps.